# Windows installer, access a custom property inside a custom action in C++

Tags: c++, windows-installer, command-line-arguments, custom-action

I have a C++ application in Visual Studio 2010 and I have a Windows Installer (i.e. setup project) to install it.  I want to be able to invoke the installer like this:

```
Setup1.msi MYPROPERTY=MyValue
```

And then be able to extract the value "MyValue" from the property from within my custom action.
I tried to get it working by following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL)(C++ custom actions) and [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16767/How-to-Pass-Command-Line-Arguments-to-MSI-Installe) (passing arguments to custom actions, but in C#) combined with some MSDN searches to get this code:

```
#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <msi.h>
#include <msiquery.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE, DWORD, LPVOID) {
    return TRUE;
}

UINT APIENTRY InstallCustomAction(MSIHANDLE install_handle) {
    static const wchar_t* kPropertyName = L"MYPROPERTY";

    //auto msi_handle = MsiGetActiveDatabase(install_handle);

    DWORD n = 0;
    //auto result = MsiGetProperty(msi_handle, kPropertyName, L"", &n);
    auto result = MsiGetProperty(install_handle, kPropertyName, L"", &n);
    wchar_t* value = nullptr;
    if (result == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
        ++n;
        value = new wchar_t[n];
        //result = MsiGetProperty(msi_handle, kPropertyName, value, &n);
        result = MsiGetProperty(install_handle, kPropertyName, value, &n);
    }

    if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        wchar_t buffer[128];
        swprintf_s(buffer, L"n = %d, value = %s", n, value);
        MessageBox(nullptr, buffer, L"CustomAction", MB_OK);

    } else {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Error reading property", L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
    delete value;
    //MsiCloseHandle(msi_handle);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm following the C# tutorial exactly in terms of the IDE (I have `Entry Point` set to `InstallCustomAction` and `Custom Action` Data set to `/MYPROPERTY=[MYPROPERTY]`) The custom action fires correctly but I don't get the parameter.

With the code as-is, I get n=0. If I use the `msi_handle` from `MsiGetActiveDatabase` I get an error (i.e. MsiGetProperty returns something other than ErrorSuccess).

**How can I get the property that the user passes in on the command line from within my custom action?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call MsiGetActiveDatabase.  From what you've written it sounds like your custom action is scheduled for deferred execution.  In that scenario you should be trying to get the property named "CustomActionData".

Comment: I Don't think it is deferred.  I have the custom action set to fire on "Install" (from the choices of install, commit, rollback and uninstall) and the message box comes up before the install finishes.  Also I don't know where I would get a "CustomActionData" property from inside my code, I do set that property in the IDE though (I set it to /MYPROPERTY=[MYPROPERTY])

Comment: It's deferred.  Setup projects don't have the ability to schedule custom actions any other way.

Comment: So I guess I don't know what deferred means in this context.  Anyway, how do I access the CustomActionData property, would it be through the MsiGetProperty function? I did all this at work and I am at home now, but I guess I can replicate the project and try it.

Comment: You'll literally do an MsiGetProperty for a property called "CustomActionData".  It'll be serialized (/KEY=VALUE) like you described above and you'll have to deserialzie it.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: So I don't need to bother with the /KEY=VALUE and I can just put [MYPROPERTY] and get the string I want directly.  I tried it and it worked, thanks.

Comment: Yes, The /KEY=VALUE is merely a simple serialization technique in case you need to pass more data.  I've blogged a similar pattern for InstallScript and also created one for C#/DTF that uses JSON.

Comment: That /key-value this is the way VS managed code installer classes work, that's their pattern. Somewhere in the interface they parse the string into a dictionary of (key,value), then the user's managed code you use the base installer class's Context.Parameters dictionary to get the value out. I think Jeremy may have seen installer class docs and assumed that C++ CAs work the same way. They don't, and VS won't package them into a C++ CA like that, although you could use that format to pass a bunch of parameters if you can parse them yourself as Chris P says.